# Directive isn't properly updating controller variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm fairly new to Angular, and I'm trying to update one of my controller's variables from a directive, but it won't seem to work. The variable is populated in the directive, and when I log it there it's fine. Then when I try to log the variable from the controller; it logs fine at first, then it's "undefined".

I have no idea why this is happening. Help :(

**Directive**

```
app.directive('reportFilter', function() { 
return { 
 restrict: 'E', 
 scope: {}, 
controller: 'MainController', 
templateUrl: 'js/directives/reportFilter.html',
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

scope.updateTable = function(selectedOffer,startDate,endDate) {
var offer='offer:'+selectedOffer.offer_id;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'daily_summary.php',
            data: { 
                'offer': selectedOffer.offer_id 
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
          scope.myvariable=response;
          scope.getData();
          console.log(scope.myvariable);
          scope.$apply();
          }
    });
    }
  }
}
```

});

**Controller**

```
  app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'service',   'Offerservice','$attrs', function($scope, service,Offerservice) {

  $scope.getData= function () {
          console.log($scope.myvariable);
          return $scope.myvariable;
      };
 }]);
```

[image: This is the console's log showing the variable become undefined again in the controller]

Comment: You set isolated scope on directive with no bindings to parent

Comment: How silly :-) It's working now, thank you!